# How to check bluetooth state in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new with Ionic 4, I am trying to check the bluetooth state with @ionic-native/diagnostic, here is my code
app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    CheckRegInfo
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    CheckRegInfo
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Diagnostic,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The checking function:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AlertController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Diagnostic} from "@ionic-native/diagnostic/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-check',
  templateUrl: 'check.html'
})
export class CheckRegInfo {
  logowhitesrc:string = "assets/imgs/logowhite.png";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private alertController:AlertController, private diagnostic: Diagnostic) {

  }
  checkBluetoothState(){
    let titleStr: string;
    this.diagnostic.getBluetoothState()
      .then((state) => {
        if (state == this.diagnostic.bluetoothState.POWERED_ON){
          titleStr = "Okay"
        } else {
          titleStr = "Not Okay"
        }
      }).catch(e => console.error(e));
    let addAlert = this.alertController.create({
      title:"Bluetooth state",
      message:titleStr
    });
    addAlert.present();
  }

}
```

But when I try this on the device, there is no response ? I try on the ionic serve -> it going to the error Object(...) is not a function

Comment: where are u calling checkBluetoothState()?

Comment: I call it via a button on my screen
<button ion-button (click)="checkBluetoothState()">Check</button>

Comment: in your device, are you getting an alert?

Comment: It no response at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
declare let cordova: any;

@Component({
 selector: 'page-check',
 templateUrl: 'check.html'
})

export class CheckRegInfo {
  logowhitesrc : string = "assets/imgs/logowhite.png";

  constructor(public navCtrl          : NavController, 
              private alertController : AlertController, 
              private diagnostic      : Diagnostic) {}

checkBluetoothState(){
   let titleStr: string;
   cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getBluetoothState().then((state) => {
    if (state == cordova.plugins.diagnostic.bluetoothState.POWERED_ON){
      titleStr = "Okay";
      showAlert(titleStr);
    } else {
      titleStr = "Not Okay";
      showAlert(titleStr);
    }
  }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}

showAlert(title){
  let addAlert = this.alertController.create({
    title  :"Bluetooth state",
    message:titleStr
 });
 addAlert.present();
}
```

According to the docs, you need to call it using `cordova.plugins.diagnostic`:

> The core plugin module is exposed via the global `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` object and it aliases all functions and properties of the other optional modules.

Also, since `then()` is used for asynchronous operation, therefore you need to call the method `showAlert(titleStr)` inside of `.then()`.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, I try to follow your instruction and add cordova plugin on config.xml, specify module with preference, add bluetooth permission, but there is still no thing change,  do we need to specify cordova with some thing in this:
declare let cordova: any;

Comment: which phone are u using? Also please add console.log() immediately after method declaration, to see if it is entering the method.. Also please use chrome://inspect/ when running the app on a device

Comment: I use Samsung note FE, It call to the function checkBluetoothState already, but in ionic serve it will have a error that cordova is not defined :(

Comment: this plugin doesnt work in ionic serve (browsers), it is only for mobile phones

Comment: i understand that, but is there any problem with the declaration of cordova ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191715/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-kyo-hoai-bac).